# Django combine multiple querysets (same model)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have list of querysets (all for same model):

```
results = Entry.objects.all()
result_elms = []
if city_list:
    for city in city_list:
    result_elms.append(results.filter(address__city__icontains=city))

if county_list:
    for county in county_list:
        results_elms.append(results.filter(address__county__icontains=county))
#other filters here, daynamically created

#how can I combine all results_elms (querysets) into one?
```

I know that I can use `|` operator to combine querysets from same model.
But how can I apply it for all elements from `result_elms` list?

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question to give an answer.  You should provide enough info for someone else to reproduce the problem, and a clear description of the result you're looking for (also the `if` statement is not needed).

Comment: Have you tried it using `__in`? That should help you. See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

Comment: @thebjorn what do you mean? My exact question is how can I apply | (combine oparator) for all querysets in list. what other information should I provide?

Comment: Please specify what other filters you want to apply. What is the expected results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

results = Entry.objects.all()
q = Q()
for city in city_list:
    q = q | Q(address__city__icontains=city)
results.filter(q)
```

The documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) has more details and examples.

Comment: The little bit of extra info made it clear what you needed - happy to help :-)

Comment: Why `q = Q()` then `q = q | Q(address__city__icontains=city)`?

Comment: @ammarx because `q` needs an initial value.  It may be clearer if one writes `q |= Q(...)`?  I suppose you could initialize it with the first item in the list `q = Q(address__city__icontains=citi_list[0])` and then iterate over `city_list[1:]` -- but then you need to add back the if statement (instead of letting the for-loop skip the empty list).

Comment: You can use `results.filter(Q(address__city__icontains=city) | Q(another_filter))` as specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: @ammarx I've updated the answer with a link to the docs. The issue here though is dynamically building up the Q-expression to feed to filter.

Comment: @ammarx I've checked and you can use (in my case):
q = Entry.objects.empty()
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using at least Django 1.11, this is a one liner.

```
final_results = result_elms[0].union(*result_elms[1:])
```

here is the link to [documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union). You may refer to my [blog post](http://technowhisp.com/2017/08/08/django/django-orm-union-intersection-and-difference/) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using at least Django 3.2, this looks like

```
>>> qs1 = Author.objects.values_list('name')
>>> qs2 = Entry.objects.values_list('headline')
>>> qs1.union(qs2).order_by('name')
```

here is the link to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union).